# Json list with object and list

Tags: json

I need to parse structure like this, but I haven't got an idea how to describe it.

The json structure to parse:

```
{
"sth":[
            {
               "key_to_get":"value_to_get",
            },
            [
               
            ]
         ]
}
```

Comment: Your "structure" is an incomplete inner part of an object literal. It is missing the curly brackets around it. The following would be a valid literal: `{sth:[{key_to_get:"value_to_get" },[ ]]}`.

Comment: I not write it here, my bad. Problem is not with sth but i'm not sure how to ignore this inside list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question was: How do I get the marked key and value from the object `o`?

```
const o={sth:[{key_to_get:"value_to_get" },[ ]]}
```

Then the answer would be:

```
[key,val]=Object.entries(o.sth[0])[0];
```

If you want to get the content of the first property within your received object `o` then the following would do that:

```js
const o={sth:[{key_to_get:"value_to_get" },[ ]]};  // received object o
const [key,val]=Object.entries(Object.values(o)[0][0])[0];
console.log("the first key is:  ",key,"\nthe first value is:",val);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON uses key-value pairs so the key of the inner array is missing. And also which is mentioned before this whole thing is an object so you should put inside {}.
Something like this:

```
{
   "sth": [
            {
                "inner_object": {
                  "key_to_get": "value_to_get"
                },
                "some_array_name": []
            }
          ]
}
```

And access it like yourJsonObject.sth[0].inner_object.key_to_get

Comment: I know that it should like that, but I recive this structure from beckend which I can't modify.